# Ajax object posted to php is not seen by php

Tags: php, jquery, json, object

I am sending this:

> switch=rssAdd&data=[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Which is created by this:

```
$(xml).find('item').each(function() {
    var stage = $(this).attr('p4:stage');
    var title = $(this).find('title').text();
    var desc = $(this).find('description').text();
    var location = $(this).find('category').eq(0).text();
    var billtype = $(this).find('category').eq(1).text();
    var linkurl = $(this).find('link').text();
    var thedate = $(this).find('a10\\:updated,updated').text();
    thedate = thedate.substring(0,10);

    var todaydate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yyyy-mm-dd', new Date());

    //if(todaydate == thedate) {

    info.push({'stage': stage,'title': title,'description': desc,'location': location,'billtype': billtype,'linkurl': linkurl,'thedate': thedate});

    //}


});

console.log(info);

var senddata = json_encode(info);

$.ajax({
        url: 'php.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: 'switch=rssAdd&data='+senddata,

        success: function(result) {
            //console.log('here is the result: ' + result);
        }
});
```

And its received to a php.php file:

```
<?php
 header("Content-Type: application/json");

  include('sql.php');

  $switch = $_POST['switch'];

  switch ($switch) {

case "rssAdd":


    $info = json_decode($_POST['data']);
    print_r($info);



//  $sql = "INSERT INTO rssFeed (date, title, description, location, billtype, link) VALUES(". $t['date'] .",". $t['title'] .", ". $t['description'] .", ". $t['location'] .", ". $t['billtype'] .", ". $t['link'] .")";
     //     $inres = $mysqli->query($sql);
   //       echo "worked: ".$t['title'];

break;
   }
   ?>
```

For some reason, which I cannot really figure out, which i think is because i am not sure what type of object I am sending to the php, even though i have tried all, why its not being seen by the PHP and `print_r($info) is empty, and no error?

Any ideas ?

Thanks in Advance

Andrew

Comment: Have you tried sending it without json_encoding it first? if so, what happens?

Comment: `json_encode` should probably be `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Hiya Kyle, I have tried it without sending anything, on the assumption it is a json, as thats how I thought i created it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with your json_encode in javascript, because its result turns out to be a series of [object Object]. it's out of order.

usually use JSON.stringify to stringify a json object.